# How to analyse native memory on android?

Tags: android, native, swap

Recently, my app gets large native memory after monkey, i can not reproduced manually, so i just can analyse through Android profiler.it shows 255264K memory in swap on native heap, but i can not see it in android profiler, so i refer to smap file. i can see a large malloc with 129M on swap.

```
               Pss  Private  Private  SwapPss     Heap     Heap     Heap
             Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
            ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
```

Native Heap    75741    75496      220   255264   374656   331568    43087

Dalvik Heap     6606     5536     1032        0    18020     5748    12272

Dalvik Other     6844     6844        0       36

```
    Stack       52       52        0       24
   Ashmem       14       12        0        0
  Gfx dev    17488    16652      836        0
Other dev       21        4       16        0
 .so mmap    19382      224    14992     1063
.jar mmap        8        8        0        0
.apk mmap    19678       32    17360       20
.ttf mmap     7134        0     5752        0
.dex mmap    13703        0     8668        8
.oat mmap     2786        0      712        0
.art mmap     4541     3844      344      108
```

Other mmap     1997        4     1688        0
   EGL mtrack    29388    29388        0        0
    GL mtrack    19036    19036        0        0
      Unknown     2227     2144       76      549
        TOTAL   483718   159276    51696   257072   392676   337316    55359

9c800000-a4c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
                              [anon:libc_malloc]

Name:           [anon:libc_malloc]

Size:             135168 kB

Rss:                5296 kB

Pss:                5296 kB

Shared_Clean:          0 kB

Shared_Dirty:          0 kB

Private_Clean:         0 kB

Private_Dirty:      5296 kB

Referenced:         4788 kB

Anonymous:          5296 kB

AnonHugePages:         0 kB

Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB

Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB

Swap:             129872 kB

SwapPss:          129872 kB

KernelPageSize:        4 kB

MMUPageSize:           4 kB

Locked:                0 kB

now, my question is:
1.how can i get more information about this memory?

2.does 129M memory malloc at a time? how can application get so many momery for one time.

3.why this memory malloc on swap directly?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qCAn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a detailed information about memory consumption, you can actually use "Android Profiler". You can get a detailed information about various components that may be using / storing memory of the application.

Comment: it seems that "Android Profiler" can not get all memory, for example, it shows my app used 100M native heap, but i just can see 80M in Android Profiler.

Comment: Send a screenshot of the same. @SheldonChan

Comment: i have upload screenshot, as show, Android profiler show 52.4M native heap, but just can see 37.4 in dump.pls help me to get an answer.

Comment: It seems that the objects that have been used in the project are taking a lot of memory. In order to free memory space, you can do the following : override onTrimMemory() method , favour static inner classes instead of non static and try to use AsyncTask for small operations as it doesn't use memory that much. @SheldonChan